# Sharing google sheets udfs with coworkers and how to tell if your company uses google apps for work

Tags: google-apps-script

I read this:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries
and
[Distributing Google Apps Scripts for Sheets in your company network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567128/distributing-google-apps-scripts-for-sheets-in-your-company-network)

I have a simple udf for google sheets that I'd like to share with a couple other people.  Whenever I need it for a new sheet, I just copy and paste the code into the script editor and run a smaller function in debug mode.  Then the computer asks if I give permission to my little script to run and I say yes.  If other people want to use my udf, I can't expect them to do the same thing because they're not programmers.  Well, I'm not either, but I try.  Anyway, is there a way to share it without publishing an add-on or that domain admin sequence of events or anything involving long authentication strings or oauth2.0.  all of this is too overwhelming for me as I'm not a real programmer.

Also, is there a way to share the udf without sharing the code, because the code is constructed embarassingly and more importantly, there is some info I'm not sure I'm allowed to share.

Speaking of things I'm not sure of, I'm not sure if this counts as an app for work because we use the app for work, but it seems like your company has to pay for something to be considered an app for work even though these apps seem like they're for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is an open issue regarding [Protect Google App Script](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5850). It would be best to follow this ticket to be update on how you would be able to protect your apps script code. [Migrating your code to an external script and make it as a library would protect your code from editing but not from viewing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16078722/5995040).

Creating an app for your company may not be considered as an app for work. According to this [document](https://apps.google.com/):

> Google Apps for Work adds business-specific features such as custom email addresses at your domain (@yourcompany.com), at least 30 GB of storage for documents and email, and 24/7 phone and email support.