# How do I publish a Google Docs Add-on so only people in my G-Suite can install it?

Tags: gmail-addons

I am trying to create an Add-on for my team so everyone on who is in my G-Suite is able to access it. I want to find a way where when I publish the Add-on they are able to install it.

I don't want to publish it to the public store for anybody to download, because my code uses APIs that I pay for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567128/distributing-google-apps-scripts-for-sheets-in-your-company-network) for Google Spreadsheets the process is the same for Google Docs.

Answer (score 0):

See https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons#step_4_configure_the_marketplace_sdk

Specifically, there's a "visibility" option when publishing that allows you to restrict it to users in your domain.